# How to edit list item on another page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

**The Situation**

In Sharepoint 2010 I can click on an item in a list:

[image]

And then the Read/Edit view becomes visible in that page:

[image]

**My Goal**

I have a WebPart *on another Page* where I show some items coming from this and several other lists and I want to add a read or edit link to each of them.

How can I do that?

I'm searching for a function like `EditListItem('ItemId', 'ListId', ...)` which will open the edit div window.

**What have I tried**

The a tag generated by Sharepoint on "Test Item" above is like this:

```
<a onfocus="OnLink(this)" 
   href="http://{mysharepointsite}/_layouts/listform.aspx
         ?PageType=4
         &amp;ListId={D0FDB54F-1DDF-4C5E-865B-ABDE55C1125}
         &amp;ID=1
         &amp;ContentTypeID=0x010800ED5176D13CCEFC4AA8D62A79985DE892"
   onclick="EditLink2(this,49);return false;" target="_self">Test Item</a>
```

So I digged a bit into the Sharepoint JS files and found `EditLink2` calling `_EditLink2` which calls `ShowPopup` from the context (the `49`) is the context no and seems to be dynamic.

I tried to fake the context but there are billions of variables and I think I can't get that to work stable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On that page where you need to open dialog just write simple JS function for showing [modal dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058.aspx), for example:

```
function openMyItemDialog( itemId ) {
    var options = {
        url: "http://{mysharepointsite}/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={D0FDB54F-1DDF-4C5E-865B-ABDE55C1125}&ID=" + itemId + "&ContentTypeID=0x010800ED5176D13CCEFC4AA8D62A79985DE892&IsDlg=1",
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        title: "Item view/edit"
    };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog( options );
}
```

Note the `&IsDlg=1` param at url

And then modify href link where you display your items.

For example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="openMyItemDialog(35)">Test item</a>
```

Replace `35` to `ID` of your item

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but there's another way to achieve what the OP was trying to do.

In a XSLT ViewWebPart, there is a global parameter named $ViewCounter.
This is the context number required by the _EditLink2 function.

So, in order to add a link to the display form and have it opened in a dialog, wrap the item in an `<a>` tag like this:

```
<a href="{$HttpVDir}/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId={$List}&amp;ID={$thisNode/@ID}" onclick="EditLink2(this,{$ViewCounter});return false;">your item</a>
```

Notice the variables $HttpVDir, $List, $thisNode/@ID and $ViewCounter (no need to hard-code any value).