# Custom sharepoint 2010 xslt list - Edit item via javascript - Data not refreshed after edit

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-2010

I custom render a SharePoint 2010 list using xslt. I created links to each item in order to edit them via the SharePoint modal dialog popup UI. I used the following script in order to do so (SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog script):

```
function openMyItemDialog( itemId ) {
var options = {
    url: "http://{mysharepointsite}/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={D0FDB54F-1DDF-4C5E-865B-ABDE55C1125}&ID=" + itemId + "&ContentTypeID=0x010800ED5176D13CCEFC4AA8D62A79985DE892&IsDlg=1",
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    title: "Item view/edit"
};
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog( options );
```

}

I invoke the script with this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="openMyItemDialog(35)">Test item</a>
```

Here is a related post:
[How to edit list item on another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069102/how-to-edit-list-item-on-another-page/18089321#18089321)

**Problem**

This is a great solution, however, one thing that you have to consider is that if you edit an item, you have to refresh the the page in order to see the update(information you just changed). Are there any SharePoint scripts that will update the item on the page after the edit is made and saved?

So what happens is - after the save button is clicked, the information gets updated in SharePoint, but the modal div gets hidden and the the page information never gets updated.

Any help is welcomed.

Thanks, M31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a modal window, then you have to monitor when the modal is closed (for example with https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65513/detect-modal-dialog-close-with-jquery) then you can reload your main page with `window.location.reload()` or `window.location.href=window.location.href`